# what is derivative of $\exp(X\beta)$ w.r.t $\beta$

Tags: derivatives, self-learning, matrix-calculus

I am using the Denominator layout, i.e. $$\frac{\partial X\beta}{\partial \beta} = X^T,$$ where $X$ is $n\times p$ and $\beta$ is $p\times 1$.

What is the result of
$$\frac{\partial \exp(X\beta)}{\partial \beta} \text{ ?}$$

Since $\exp(X\beta)$ is $n\times1$ and $\beta$ is $p\times 1$, the derivative should be a $p\times n$ matrix. However, this is what I derived:

$$\frac{\partial \exp(X\beta)}{\partial \beta} = \frac{\partial X\beta}{\partial \beta}\frac{\partial \exp(X\beta)}{\partial X\beta} = X^T\exp(X\beta),$$
which is a $p\times1$. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What does $\exp(v)$ mean in this context where $v$ is $n\times 1$ ?

Comment: It is elementwise exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the chain rule:

$$f(\mathbf{x})=[e^{x_1},\ldots,e^{x_n}]^\intercal$$
$$f'(\mathbf{x})=\operatorname{diag}(e^{x_1},\ldots,e^{x_n})$$

Denoting the $i$-th row of $X$ by $\mathbf{x}_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$,
$$g(\boldsymbol{\beta})=X\boldsymbol{\beta}=[\mathbf{x}^\top_1\boldsymbol{\beta},\ldots,\mathbf{x}^\top_n\boldsymbol{\beta}]^\intercal$$
$$g'(\boldsymbol{\beta})=X$$

we obtain
$$h(\boldsymbol{\beta})=f\circ g(\boldsymbol{\beta})=[\exp(\mathbf{x}^\top_1\boldsymbol{\beta}),\ldots,\exp(\mathbf{x}^\top_n\boldsymbol{\beta})]^\intercal$$

and so,

$$
\begin{align}
h'(\boldsymbol{\beta})&=f'(g(\boldsymbol{\beta}))\,g'(\boldsymbol{\beta})=\operatorname{diag}\big(\exp(\mathbf{x}^\top_1\boldsymbol{\beta}),\ldots,\exp(\mathbf{x}^\top_n\boldsymbol{\beta})\big)\,X\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\mathbf{x}_1^\top\beta}x_{11} &\ldots&e^{\mathbf{x}_1^\top\beta}x_{1p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
e^{\mathbf{x}^\top_n\beta}x_{n1} &\ldots& e^{\mathbf{x}^\top_n\beta}x_{np}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

The last matrix can be express in a more compact way in terms of Kronecker product, which is very used in higher level languages such as MatLab, R, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake was in $\frac{\partial \exp(X\beta)}{\partial X\beta}$.

Answer (score 1):

For typing convenience, define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
y &= X\beta \quad&\implies\quad &dy = X\,d\beta \\
e &= \exp(y) \quad&\implies\quad &E = {\rm Diag}(e) \\
}$$
The differential of an elementwise function requires an elementwise/Hadamard product, which can be replaced by the standard product with a diagonal matrix.
$$\eqalign{
de &= e\odot dy = E\,dy \\
}$$
Substitute $dy\,$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
de &= EX\,d\beta \\
\frac{\partial e}{\partial\beta} &= EX \\
}$$
Or in your preferred layout convention $\,X^TE^T$
$$\eqalign{
}$$

Comment: What is the dimention of $e$? Since $y$ is $n\times 1$, should $e$ also be $n\times 1$?

Comment: @mxdxzxyjzx  An element-wise function produces a result which is the same shape as its argument.